# Using symbolic links with git

Tags: git, symbolic-link, arch-linux

I used to have my system configuration files all in one directory for better management but now i need to use some version control on it.

But the problem is that git doesn't understand symbolic links that point to outside of the repository, and i can't invert the role ( having the real files on the repository and the symbolic links on their proper path ) since some files are read before the kernel loads.

I think that I can use unison to sync the files in the repo and and the their paths, but it's just not practical.
And hard links will probably be broken.
Any idea ?

Comment: How would hard links be broken?

Comment: When i make git checkouts or apply patch or rebase for example.

Answer (score 2):

If manually is the only way those files are edited, you could put the canoncial versions into the system config dir and set up a post-commit hook in git that would copy them out to their 'real' locations.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian and derived distributions, you can use [etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/) to manage `/etc`. It's as simple as installing etckeeper, running `etckeeper init` once and running `etckeeper commit` when you've changed something.

I don't know if etckeeper is directly available for Arch Linux, but there are [success](http://blogs.gurulabs.com/tim/2009/06/my-way-of-keeping-arch-linux-u.html) [reports](http://aymanh.com/version-control-linux-configuration-files-etc-etckeeper) on the web.

Etckeeper uses git hooks to handle metadata such as permissions, ownership and symbolic links.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--work-tree` flag and the `--git-dir` flag (`git help git`, set both to absolute paths and make an alias) to have the .git folder outside the versioned directory.

Answer (score -2):

Make it hard links, and not soft links.

I have the same problem, I use etckeeper, and it copies my files into /etc, which I don't want.

So, instead of

```
ln -s /srv/www/site/apache.conf srv_site.com
```

do

```
ln /srv/www/site/apache.conf srv_site.com
```

and it works! :D

Comment: no hasrd links will be broken by git, actually i found the solution here : http://tensixtyone.com/perma/the-version-controlled-home-directory

Comment: The link in the previous comment by @AlfredoPalhares is broken, so we don't know what the solution was anymore.

Comment: @ywarnier Thank you archive.org for not letting internet die: https://web.archive.org/web/20120325085518/http://tensixtyone.com/perma/the-version-controlled-home-directory